# Why isn't array[i] < min && min = array[i]; grammatically correct?

Tags: javascript

```html
 <script>
    // let min =;
    // let max = ;

    function minMax(array) {
      let min = 0;
      let max = 0;

      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] < min && min = array[i];
        array[i] > max && max = array[i];




      }

    }
  </script>
```

VS Code says there are two problems, ';' is expected, but I've already provided the ';'.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pETuA.png)

I don't know what to do, a if sentence can avoid this issue, but I'd like to know why the above way isn't working.

Comment: The part on the left of the `=` is where the data on the right of the `=` will be stored. How would you store `array[i]` inside of the expression `array[i] < min && min`? It doesn't make sense, which is why that's an error. I think you just have what each side is for confused.

Comment: btw, your starting values should be better the first value of the array instead of zero. if you do not want to take them, you could [`Number.MAX_VALUE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE) and the negative value of it.

Comment: @NinaScholz Or just `-Infinity`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that, you should wrap it with parentheses

```
    array[i] < min && (min = array[i]);
    array[i] > max && (max = array[i]);
```

Comment: …though actually you **should** write `if (array[i] < min) min = array[i]; if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];` for readable, concise and idiomatic code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).